# Removing the logged in user's name from the list of users in django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have a template that displays the numbers of likes and name of the users liked the forum. But I don't want the request.user's (logged in user's) name in the list, I just want the other user's name and not the user itself. How do I achieve this? And also I want the list of the names in the reverse order in the template (now its showing the latest liked user in the last of the list.). Please guide me. Thank you.

[image]

forums.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load forum_tags %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Logged in as -- {{request.user}}</h2>
<h1>Forums:</h1>
    {% if forums.count > 0 %}
        {% for forum in forums %}
            <h2><a href="/forum/get/{{forum.id}}/">{{forum.question}}</a></h2>
            <p>{{forum.body | truncatewords:"30"}}</p>
            {% if user in forum.likes.all and forum.likes.count > 1 %}
                <p><a href="/forum/delete_likes/{{forum.id}}/">Unlike</a> You and {{forum.likes.count | substract:1}} others liked</p>
            {% elif user in forum.likes.all %}
                <p>You liked it</p>
            {% else %}
                <p><a href="/forum/update_likes/{{forum.id}}/">Like</a></p>
            {% endif %}
            {% for likes in forum.likes.all %}
                <li><a href="/get/{{likes.user}}">{{likes.get_full_name}}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <p>Sorry! No forum to display.</p>
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

snippet of views.py:

```
def forums(request):
    forums = Forum.objects.all()
    c = {'forums': forums}
    return render(request, 'forums.html', c)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`RequestContext()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) while passing context to template. It will add `user` context parameter , then you can compare it in your template as

```
{% for likes in forum.likes.all %}
   {% if user != likes.user %} 
                <li><a href="/get/{{likes.user}}">{{likes.get_full_name}}</a></li>
    {%endif%}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I'm using render in my views, and tried your way, but nothing seems to have changed...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like that ?

```
{% for likes in forum.likes.all %}
    {% if user != likes.user %}
        <li><a href="/get/{{likes.user}}">{{likes.get_full_name}}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to compare it with fullname, as I was displaying the users full name in the list. So, this was the solution:

```
        {% for likes in forum.likes.all.reverse %}
            {% if user.get_full_name != likes.get_full_name %}
                <li><a href="/get/{{likes.user}}">{{likes.get_full_name}}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

Hope this will be helpful to someone as it was for me. And thanks for all those who helped me!